# How to store temporary data for a user just for their session?

Tags: sessions

I need to allow a user to add articles to a wishlist that they can then e-mail or print. The data doesn't need to be saved or last longer than their session.

Is there a native EE way of doing this without writing a plugin myself? Or can anyone recommend a plugin that they know does this and that they have experience with please?

Comment: Ben Croker's [Session Variables](http://www.putyourlightson.net/session-variables-plugin) plugin may be useful for you. It allows you to manipulate PHP session variables without writing to the DB...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would try a 3rd party favorites/bookmark addon like [Remember Me](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/remember-me). Then you would need to dump that info into a form to send off in an email or print.

Comment: Great add-on. Solves the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

[Session Variables](http://www.putyourlightson.net/session-variables-plugin) is a great little plugin and we've used it without any issue. Easy to setup and does what you need.

Comment: This ought to do the trick. Just a reminder to use an add-on like [IfElse](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ifelse) or [Switchee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/switchee) (nestable; same developer, Mark Croxton) so you're only calling the instance you need. May not need it, just throwing that in there just in case. [Mo Variables](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mo-variables) provides a variable for detecting ajax requests. With these you ought to be able to just use templates instead of writing an add-on.

Comment: I've never used Session Variables before, but looking at the docs I'm confused on how you add multiple entries to a session and then dump (get) those variables. It seems each entry would need a unique name whereas Remember Me seems straight forward in this case.

Answer (score 5):

It's pretty easy to save user-scoped data in Stash; by default this will expire at the end of the user's session. You could save just the entry ids or the whole entry.

```
{exp:stash:append_list name="wishlist" save="yes" replace="yes"}
{stash:entry_id}67{/stash:entry_id}
{/exp:stash:append_list}
```

Comment: Hmm, ok, thanks, i'll take a look. I'm going to use "Remember Me" for now as it ticks all the boxes, but i'll have a dig around with stash and see if it can do all i need. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

i have happily used http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/remember-me a few times. super easy to work with, and to configure. did not use session variables yet though